# How do I query a MongoDB in Apache NiFi based on a dynamic value?

Tags: mongodb, apache-nifi

I'm trying to run a GetMongo Processor in Apache NiFi. I can get a base query to run just fine and output the records to my hard drive (just for initial testing. Will go to a Hadoop client eventually)

My problem is I want to run the query every 10 minutes and return ONLY new records in the last 10 minutes. The query I have tested on my local Mongo client is:

```
{"createdAt": {$gte: new Date(ISODate().getTime() - 1000 * 60 * 5)}}
```

At first, I thought it didn't like the dynamic part, so I tried putting in a static timestamp. But NiFi has told me every single query I have tried is invalid.

There are some decent guides but are very specific to SQL processors in NiFi and wondering if anyone has experience with creating a flow based on dynamic queries with Mongo in NiFi. Thanks so much in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get ISO string in Nifi getMongo Query Field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44573618/how-to-get-iso-string-in-nifi-getmongo-query-field)